# how can I open word document using tsql stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, doc

I have a directory of word documents and a database that lists the document names.  I have a stored procedure that I can pull the document file name.  I would like to be able to open the work document from the stored procedure.

Is this possible from a tsql stored procedure?

Thanks in advance
Dean-O

Comment: "Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could that they didn't stop to think if they should." - Dr. Ian Malcolm, Jurassic Park.  Stop and think if you should. :-)

Comment: You mean like using [`xp_cmdshell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)? What do you suppose Word would interact with?

Comment: really not clear. Have you read about Filestream ?

Comment: for clarity... I have an application that accesses word documents in a network folder.  I want to create a process where in the application I have the end user click a button which calls a SP I created and it will then access one of the saved word documents from the SP.  Does this help clarify the quest?  Thanks Dean-O

Comment: IMO, you should consider separating your business logic with persistence layer

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I just stumbled upon this and it looks like no one provided an actual answer.

My situation is I have a database project that is setup for automatic deployment.  In the build directory I want to have a folder full of documentation files written in HTML.  I wanted to write a sproc that you maybe pass in the name of a sproc and it will find the appropriate file and open it up in your default browser.

My first thought was to use xp_cmdshell or a CLR procedure.  The problem is when you run these it is going to run on the server which probably will not be your local machine in which case you wont be getting the desired result.  So I would say the answer is No you cannot do this.